# Where can I find a nice File Broswer library for PHP?

Tags: php, file-management

This is my case:

I'm developing a plugin for Wordpress.
I am to browse my server side file directory (uploads) and retrieve a url for a selected file.

I'm planning to do this through jQuery (but not flash).

Are there any good libraries out there for browsing files on a server??

Comment: Typically in a normal hosting you should have an access like that in your panel (CPanel or other).

Comment: yes but he wants a quick way to find those url's, and not having to go to his cpanel each time he wants to retrieve a link. i for example have to login each time i access my hosting panel

Comment: The goal is to relate an image to a page or post by using custom properties. To avoid having to type the image path, I'm creating a pop-up window (Thickbox) where I can browse for a image and return the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this fit your needs? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/filebrowser/

looks clean and you can browse all the folders

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice start. It'll def. help me with I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at:

- [FileRun](http://www.filerun.com/?gclid=CPTS1u-v1aMCFcpS6wodWxfCvw)
- [fileNice](http://filenice.com/)
- [Web File Browser](http://webfilebrowser.sourceforge.net/)
- [enCode eXplorer](http://encode-explorer.siineiolekala.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. 
It requires you install a PC client and a single file php server. But it runs fast!
It is designed for wordpress.

http://the-sync-star.com/